# Display particular Image Style for image based on Role of User?

Tags: 7, users, media

Using [ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) there are 2 different Image Styles - e.g. S1 and S2.

What needs to happen:

- User A has Role Y and when s/he views a node/user profile should always be presented with S1 images.
- User B has Role Z and when s/he views a node/user profile should always be presented with S2 images.

What are the different ways this can be achieved? All suggestions very welcome.

Comment: Basically, in .php.tpl file, u need to use the global user, get the global user role. Then use a simple php if statement, If role = x then picture gets applied s1 style. If role = Y then S2. Sorry, I don't provide code answers.

Comment: I was thinking the same. But I'm still wondering if there's a way that doesn't involve the template files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hook_preprocess_image_style to alter the style name to use:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK for theme image_style.
 */
 function mymodule_preprocess_image_style(&$variables) {
   $style = mymodule_determine_style_to_use($variables);
   $variables['style_name'] = $style;
 }
```

Take care that you do not alter all image styles, but only those you want/need to change, so mymodule_determine_style_to_use() should e.g have a check on $variables['style_name'] being S1 or S2.

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure [Image Style Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_style_access) module.

> Allows granular access control to images and image style
>   derivatives.This module provides access control for image files. Each
>   access configuration can be set to allow or deny access to images and
>   their derivatives by:
>
> File source (scheme), Base image file location and Image style.

Comment: I think this doesn't work. When access is denied no image is displayed rather than the correct image.

Answer (score 0):

I have learnt that this can be accomplished without code using https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc

Thank you to those who posted answers.