# Change image style during hook_node_view()

Tags: 7, media

I'd like to programmatically change an image style during hook_node_view(), and I thought this would be relatively straightforward like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view()
 */
function example_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  if (example_ok()) {
    $node->content['field_image'][0]['#image_style'] = 'new_image_style';
  }

}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I'm aware of the picture and breakpoints modules, and am in fact using them, however there are sometimes when a dynamic decision needs to be made that these modules don't cover.

Comment: You could also have a look at [display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) and create multiple view-modes for your nodes. Then you can style the image per view-mode. If that makes sense for your use-case

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this will not be acceptable for this project as I'd hate to turn on a very feature rich/heavy module for something that seems like a single line of code should be able to cover.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to answer my own question, *but* [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/185327/10645) pointed me in the right direction. Here's the [hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x) that worked in this case:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function example_preprocess_image_style(&$variables) {
  if (example_ok()) {
    $variables['style_name'] = 'new_image_style';  
  }
}

function example_ok() {
  global $user;
  // If the logged in user is bob, everything is ok.
  if ($user->uid && $user->name == 'bob') {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I must agree with example_ok ;)